# QLineEdit::setInputMask( const QString &mask ) - does not work

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit, input-mask

Here is the code:

```
// Latitude line edit
QLineEdit *lineEdit = new QLineEdit;
lineEdit->setInputMask( ">\N999999.99;_" );
```

But, I am getting compiler warning: Unknown escape sequence '\N'
and QLineEdit text does not contain 'N' character, only '_'.
What am I doing wrong?
Than you all in advance.

Comment: TBH, what you did wrong is not looking up the term "escape sequence".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, there is a set of defined escape sequences to store special characters into a string.

You are actually lucky that `\N` is not within this set, because then you wouldn't even get a compiler warning; the text of the warning could have made you learn about *escape sequences* (unfortunately, it didn't).

Because the `\` is used to prefix an escape sequence, you cannot use it directly; it has to be escaped itself:

```
">\\N999999.99;_"
```

This compiles to a single `>\N999999.99;_` in the output.